# When does creationTime or lastSignInTime of firebase.auth.UserMetadata returned as null/undefined?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I bumped into this issue while trying to create `user` document in Firestore after a new user is signed up using Firebase Authentication.

In `user` document, I want to include `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` fields but found out that [those fields are optional](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata). That means I would have to make those fields in my `user` document optional as well but I am not quite convinced why they should be optional in the first place. I just cannot think of a case where those fields in `metadata` of [User instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user?hl=en) **should be** set as `undefined` when it is returned after successful sign up/in using Firebase Auth.

If there's no specific case where they're returned as `undefined`, I'm planning to make those fields in my `user` document as required fields, and throw error just in case they are returned as `undefined`.

For example using `react-native-firebase`:

```
try {
  const { user } = await auth().signInAnonymously();
  const {
    metadata: { creationTime, lastSignInTime },
    uid,
  } = user;

  if (creationTime == null) {
    throw new TypeError('creationTime is returned as undefined');
  }
  if (lastSignInTime == null) {
    throw new TypeError('lastSignInTime is returned as undefined');
  }
  await firestore().collection('user').doc(uid).set({ 
    creationTime,
    lastSignInTime,
    // other fields
  });
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

But if not, then no choice but to have them as optional as well.

So wrapping up the question, is there any case where `creationTime` or `lastSignInTime` is set to `undefined`/`null`? Is it safe to just treat them as required fields?

(A similar issue is posted [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2763) but it's closed with no answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about creationTime but lastSignInTime can be undefined/null if the sign-up has occurred but the user has not signed in yet. For example the user might have to complete email verification or something along those lines.